# Rxjs poll object details first then repeated poll based on an object's status if needed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to know the best practice on doing the following in angular RxJS.

1. on page load, I need to http get the details of an object
2. based on the status of the object, I need to either repeatedly poll the status of the object until it is READY, if it is not ready. Or stop polling if it is ready.
3. The status of the object can be changed from ready to not ready, or not ready to ready at any time. This can be set from the poll result, or set by the user on demand when a user wants.

I have tried something similar to the following, but feel it is not the best solution:

```js
this.http.getObjectDetails(this.id).subscribe()

timer(1000, 1000)
      .pipe(
        filter(() => this.object.status != 'READY'),
        concatMap(() => {
          return this.http.checkObjectStatus(this.id)
        })
      ).subscribe()
```

First, it does not concat the two subscriptions, and secondly, I am not sure it can handle the situation that the status changed from ready to not ready.

Thanks

Comment: if  we stop to polling when it is ready how we can know  the status change to not ready ?

Comment: @ArashHatami. I have a ui button allow the user to check to force check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expand operator for a simple "conditional repeat" behavior.

```
this.http.getObjectDetails(this.id).subscribe()
let request = this.http.checkObjectStatus(this.id);

request.pipe(
  expand(
    res => {
      if (res.status == 'READY') {
        return empty();
      }
      else {
        return timer(1000).pipe(
          map(() => {
            return request
          })
        );
      }
    }
  ),
).subscribe(res => { });
```

also import

```
import { empty } from 'rxjs';
import { expand } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: `this.request` is undefined after subscribed. Your code will give an error

Comment: @JingshaoChen this is sample :)) not for copy paste , ok i will edit it now

Comment: Your answer calls request in a loop and fires bunch of extra requests every seconds. and it does not call get details at first

Comment: @JingshaoChen You are right , check it again , thanks

Comment: this still does not guarantee get status is run **after** get details. Say get details is delayed for 5 seconds, get status will run 5 times when get details resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a function that calls itself recursively until the response is ready.

```js
const { of, iif } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, tap, delay } = rxjs.operators;

const http = url => of({ STATUS: (Math.random() > .7) ? 'READY' : 'NOT READY' })

const getObjectDetails = (id) => http(`url/{id}`).pipe(
  tap(result => { console.log(result.STATUS); }),
  switchMap(result => iif(() => result.STATUS === 'READY', of(result), getObjectDetails(id)))
);

getObjectDetails(1).subscribe(result => { console.log('finished'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```